# Set a custom Transaction ID from an external source

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to change the Transaction ID straight after the user finishes the checkout process.

After the user has clicked submit, I'd like to change the Transaction ID to an ID that I'm retrieving from a 3rd party (POS system), and then add it into the database as per usual.

I've managed to get the correct ID from the POS system, but I'm not sure what file to edit in order to change the Transaction ID before it goes into the database.